# Apple or Google have USB keys that can be used for MFA

Tags: ios, google-play

I am creating a google account and an apple ID with a group work account. During registration, it asks for entering a mobile number to be linked to that account where they can send a verification code to it. This account will be used by a group of people and I dont want to put just a personal mobile number and I dont want to buy a new mobile number as it wont be used by anyone and it will expire sooner or later. Is there any other option? I am not sure if Apple or Google have USB keys that can be used for MFA instead of a mobile number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about iOS. But Google offers a variety of means, including printed backup codes. [They are described here](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/features.html). Yubico also [offers hardware keys than can be used](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006418-using-your-yubikey-with-google).